# For a $7 \times 7$ complex matrix $A$ with $A^3=0$ and Rank$A^2=2$ what will be Nullity A?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $A$ be a Complex $7 \times 7 $ matrix satisfying the following two conditions: $A^3=0$, Rank$A^2=2$. Then I have to calculate Nullity$A$.

My effort: Using the formula Rank$A^2 \geq 2 \text {Rank}(A)-7$ we have Rank$A\leq 4$ i.e., Nullity$A \geq 3.$ On the other hand Rank$A > \text{Rank}A^2,$ since Range$A$=Range$A^2$ will imply Range$A^2$= Range$A^3$ and then $A^2=0.$ Therefore Rank$A \geq 3.$ So $3 \leq \text{Rank A} \leq 4,$ equivalently $3 \leq \text{Nullity A} \leq 4.$ I cannot proceed further. I need some help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Suppose $A$ is in its Jordan form. We have the only eigenvalue of $A$ is $0$(why?). From $\operatorname{Rank}(A^2)=2$, you have only finite possibilities of combination of Jordan blocks. Try to find all of them and apply the Rank-Nullity theorem to simplify your calculation, i.e., it only leaves you to find all the possibilities of the rank of $A$.

Comment: I thought there could be some elementary solution. Indeed if I use counting of Jordan blocks there is $2$ elementary Jordan blocks  of size $3$ corresponding to the eigen value $0,$ but then there should be another block of  size $1$ and Nullity$A$ is exactly the number of Jordan blocks.